# DIVs pull apart when scaling down

Tags: html, css

Within a single-column CSS grid, I have a div running a js slideshow that sits atop a second div. When I scale the site down, those two divs pull away from each other. I would like to be able to maintain a constant distance between the two divs, but I can't get that to work. The div classes in question are "slides" and "centertext".

[Here's a link to the site at codepen](https://codepen.io/Dutchg/pen/KBWpyO)

Thank you for any help.

Here's the HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="created" content="Fri, 22 Jan 2016 17:43:40 GMT" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="jvs_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</head>
  <body>

<div id="wrap">

<div class="maingrid">

<div class="slides">
    <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out1.png" max-width:100%;>
    <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out2.png" max-width:100%;>
    <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out3.png">
    <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out4.png">
    <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out5.png">
    <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out6.png">  
    <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out7.png">
    <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out8.png">
    <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out9.png">
    <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out10.png">
  </div><!-- end of slides div --> 

<div class="centertext">
    <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/images/JVSA_weblogo3.png" width="281" height="106" alt="" title="" border="0" />
    <p class="name">FIRSTNAME LASTNAME</p>
    <p class="address">1234 Example Street<br>
    Princeton, New Jersey 12345<br>
    testing@email.net<br>
    505.422.6563</p>
    <p>Solemnly he came forward and mounted the round gunrest. He faced about and blessed gravely thrice the tower, the surrounding country and the awaking mountains. Then, catching sight of Stephen Dedalus, he bent towards him and made rapid crosses in the air, gurgling in his throat and shaking his head. Stephen Dedalus, displeased and sleepy, leaned his arms on the top of the staircase and looked coldly at the shaking gurgling face that blessed him, equine in its length, and at the light untonsured hair, grained and hued like pale oak.
    </p>

  </div><!-- end of centertext div -->  

</div><!-- end of maingrid div -->  

</div><!-- end of wrap div -->  


<script>
function nextSlide() {
    var q = function(sel) { return document.querySelector(sel); }   
    q(".slides").appendChild(q(".slides img:first-child"));
}
setInterval(nextSlide, 5000)
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS

```
#wrap {
      max-width:100%;
      width:1000px;
      background:#FFF;
      margin: 0 auto;
}

.maingrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  margin-top:50px;
}

.centertext {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  margin-top:20px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align:left;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 19px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  color:#000000;
  font-size:1em;
  line-height: 20px; 
}


img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}   


.name {
    font-size:1.5em;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-variant:small-caps;
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
}

.address {
    margin-top: 8px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#000000;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height: 19px; 
}

/* the slide container with a fixed size */
.slides {
  width:100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 670px;
  position: relative;
}

/* the images are positioned absolutely to stack. opacity transitions are animated. */
.slides img { 
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute; 
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  width:100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-bottom:60px;
}

/* the first image is the current slide. it's faded in. */
.slides img:first-child { 
  z-index: 2; /* frontmost */
  opacity: 1;
}

/* the last image is the previous slide. it's behind the current slide and it's faded over. */
.slides img:last-child {
  z-index: 1; /* behind current slide */
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm the issue you are highlighting is the way the suddenly jump apart as you zoom IN and the slide approaches / exceeds the screen size?

Comment: Sorry, I missed this question. The issue is when you make the browser window smaller and the image shrinks, it pulls away from the text below it. I'd like them to stay the same distance from each other, in terms of the vertical space between them.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is to do with the fixed height on the .slides div.  As you zoom in the width of the visible image is not allowed to overflow the page width, so eventually the .slides div contains significant white-space at the bottom.

It can be fixed by changing

```
.slides img { 
  ...
  width:100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  ...
}
```

to

```
.slides img { 
  ...
  width: 1000px;
  ...
}
```

Assuming that does not impact some other behaviour (looks fine to me in chrome on your CodePen demo)

Comment: thanks for taking a look. I can't get your fix to work, though. I've implemented the change you suggest [at codepen](https://codepen.io/Dutchg/pen/KBWpyO), but the two divs are still pulling apart when I scale down the page. I may have misunderstood your advice.